# How to deal with seldom used big database and postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, azure-vm, postgresql-performance

I loaded in PostgreSQL (9.3) OpenStreetMap data for whole europe (400gb). Then I installed a geocoding api (nominatim) that queries the database with gis queries.

My problem is :

> This database is queried a few times a day, but because postgres loads
>   the data in its buffer on demand, my first query on a particular gps
>   point is always slow, and I do only one query per GPS point, so it's
>   always slow (like 60sec slow against 100ms when the data is buffered)

.

What could I do here ?

- I'm using a A6 Azure instance (4 Cores, 28 GB memory, HDD).
- Server is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- Swapping is enabled
- There is index on the geometry columns queried.
- The shared buffer is 10GB
- work mem is 256MB
- maintenance work mem is 4GB

Comment: What do the queries look like? When you say index on the geometry column, do you mean spatial index?  (i.e. do you use postgis?)

Comment: @dbilid yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your usage, you could try to partition the data to reduce the scanned data (at 400gb even your indexes are large and heavy to read...)
I think it's your best option as working with 400gb tables is heavy even on a very optimized queries...
You could also pre-warm the cache with the index data , by issuing some of your queries on frequent gps points or by using something like [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgprewarm.html)

Comment: I don't have a lot of control on the data structure :( And I use postgre 9.3 so there is no prewarm. Do you thin prewarm would work here with a 400gb and a 10gb shared buffer ?

Comment: Partitions are almost transparent to the application - if there's a good clause to partition by it might work with a couple of triggers... 400gb on 10 gb buffers won't work- you might get part of the index inside... as for pg_prewarm , you can just run a couple of queries yourself if the points you get are not totally random.